# Devise: authentication_token column in user model is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I just created a sample application with devise plugin installed. I have `:token_authenticatable` in my user model but for some reason when I create a user it creates it with `authentication_token` column as `NULL`.

It looks like you need to set `u.ensure_authentication_token!` when creating a new user to generate a token.

Am I missing something or I need to override devise's code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your user class, just add

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable #...etc
  before_save :ensure_authentication_token
end
```

that's a devise method that will set your authentication_token.

Comment: I added that in HomeController but I'm getting the following error undefined method `before_save' for HomeController:Class

Comment: @ed1t Not the controller, the user class. I edited the answer to be more explicit

Comment: I'm using mongo_mapper and mm_devise adapter. When I add before_save .. I've got error "undefined local variable or method `to_adapter' for User:Class". Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @mike: sorry, haven't used the mongo-mapper devise. I'd start with comparing how `rails generate mongo_mapper:devise User` differs from your code, it might be a simple includes statement that you're missing

Comment: Thanks for this!  I was under the impression that Devise would generate a token automatically for new users, but I guess I was wrong (or at least it doesn't do it on its own anymore).

Comment: Can authentication_token be any random string? Or does it have to be specifically calculated? Reason I ask is because i'd like to inject users directly into my database, but I'm not sure what to put for the authentication_token.

Comment: It can be any string.